# Windows + Python 2.7 64 bit: "pip install [anypackage]" freezes

Tags: python-2.7, 64-bit, pip

I am working on a **Windows 7, 64 bit** system and I have installed **Python 2.7.12 64 bit**.
(Prior to this, I had a Python 2.7 32 bit install in which pip worked perfectly, which I uninstalled).

Now, whenever I try to install a package using pip, it freezes right after displaying **"Collecting [package name]"**, as shown below:
[image]

(The German text is just the equivalent of "This program has stopped functioning" in the English versions of Windows).

I have tried installing several packages like this (at first I thought it's a problem related to the specific package I was trying to install), but I always get the same error.

Any suggestions regarding what might be happening here?

**Edit: Just in case it's relevant: I have Cygwin installed on my machine, but I am not using python & pip in a Cygwin terminal. They are used in the normal Windows command line.**

Comment: is Cygwin/bin added at the beginning of your path? maybe you are using cygwin python. Try printing the environment variables and check that your windows python prevails the cygwin one.

Comment: Also attempt to run it with python -m pip install numpy

Comment: @Har Tried both suggestions, thanks! Unfortunately, I still have the same problem, even after completely removing Cygwin from my path.

Comment: Oh!! how about uninstalling pip and reinstalling pip as pip maybe a 32 bit process, whereas your python is now a 64 bit process. If you download the pip tar from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip and perform a python setup.py install

Comment: Windows PATH contain actual paths to python 64bit and pip?

Comment: @Har I uninstalled pip with "pip uninstall pip", then got the tar and did "python setup.py install". Both processes seemed to finish successfully, yet it still doesn't work. I hope "python setup.py install" was smart enough to automatically try to install the 64 bit pip...

Comment: @MartinP Yes -- if I just execute "pip" in the command line, I get the default help listing with the available options. It only freezes when I do "pip install [package]". Python also works correctly.

Comment: Maybe try uninstall current python 64 bit, clean Windows PATH, delete all python folders which still exists after uninstall and install python again. It sounds a bit ugly but who knows:)